# How to add value in object array inside other object array in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new in React native and I want to add value inside object array inside another object array. I have data like this :

```
dataAttribute: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'A',
          data: [
            { id: '1', name: 'First Name', type: 'text' },
            { id: '2', name: 'Last Name', type: 'text' },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'B',
          data: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Twitter', type: 'text' },
            { id: '2', name: 'Twitter follower', type: 'number' },
          ],
        }
      ]
```

and i want add params 'statusSelected == true' inside child array like this:

```
dataAttribute: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'A',
          data: [
            { id: '1', name: 'First Name', type: 'text', statusSelected: true},
            { id: '2', name: 'Last Name', type: 'text' },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'B',
          data: [
            { id: '1', name: 'Twitter', type: 'text' },
            { id: '2', name: 'Twitter follower', type: 'number' },
          ],
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
dataAttribute = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'A',
      data: [
        { id: '1', name: 'First Name', type: 'text' },
        { id: '2', name: 'Last Name', type: 'text' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'B',
      data: [
        { id: '1', name: 'Twitter', type: 'text' },
        { id: '2', name: 'Twitter follower', type: 'number' },
      ],
    }
  ]

const changeMe = (dataAttribute, attrId, dataId) => dataAttribute.map(x => x.id === attrId ? {...x, data: x.data.map(y => y.id === dataId ? {...y, statusSelected: true} : y)} : x)

console.log(changeMe(dataAttribute, 1, "1"))
```

output:

```
[ { "id": 1, "title": "A", "data": [ { "id": "1", "name": "First Name", "type": "text", "statusSelected": true }, { "id": "2", "name": "Last Name", "type": "text" } ] }, { "id": 2, "title": "B", "data": [ { "id": "1", "name": "Twitter", "type": "text" }, { "id": "2", "name": "Twitter follower", "type": "number" } ] }
```

Attached [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dv1rxtym/) for result.

Answer (score 2):

You can map over the array until you find the element where you want to add the extra data. Assuming you know the id and sub id where you want to add the info:

```
const updatedDataAttribute = dataAttribute.map((item) => {
  if (item.id === <desired item id>) {
    return {
      ...item,
      data: item.data.map((datum) => {
        if (datum.id === <desired sub item id>) {
          return {
            ...datum,
            statusSelected: true,
          }                
        }

        return datum
      }),
    }
  }

  return item
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this is to simply mutate the object, by defining the `statusSelected` attribute as `true` on the first item of the data array.

So, suppose you have `dataAttribute` defined in an object like so:

```
  var object = {
    dataAttribute: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'A',
      data: [
        { id: '1', name: 'First Name', type: 'text' },
        { id: '2', name: 'Last Name', type: 'text' },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'B',
      data: [
        { id: '1', name: 'Twitter', type: 'text' },
        { id: '2', name: 'Twitter follower', type: 'number' },
      ],
    }
  ]
  }

   // add statusSelected to the first item of the nested data array
   object.dataAttribute[0].data[0].statusSelected = true;
```

This will produce the updated object that you need.